# How to right justify a table cell using package tabular

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, cell

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{p{0.5\textwidth} p{0.5\textwidth}}
\toprule
                                  & rtcol0  \\
 leftcol1                     & rtcol1  \\
 leftcol2                     & rtcol2   \\
 leftcol3                     & rtcol3  \\
 leftcol4                     & rtcol4  \\
\midrule
Ref:                          & Date:\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\vspace{2cm}

I want the table to be "textwidth" wide with the right column right aligned.
With this code the right column is left aligned.
Is there a simple way to achieve this, hopefully, using only the package tabular?

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry about the lack of formatting. This is my first post.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Is there a chance that the cell contents of either the first or second column will never need to be line-broken? Please advise.

Comment: No. The cell contents will not overflow.

Answer (score 2):

As you've discovered, the contents of a `p`-type column are left-aligned (as well as fully justified) by default. To change its behavior to right-alignment, it's necessary to (a) load the `array` package and (b) issue a directive such as

```
>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{...}
```

If you have a need for several columns with right-aligned contents that require automatic line-breaking, it makes sense to create a new column type for it, say via

```
\newcolumntype{q}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
```

When calculating the *usable* column widths, don't forget to subtract multiples of `\tabcolsep` as needed. In the code below, this multiple is `1`.

Incidentally, the `times` package is obsolete; don't use it. Instead, load the `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` packages.

Finally, don't forget to issue a `\noindent` directive immediately before `\begin{tabular}`, as otherwise the whole `tabular` environment will be right-indented in the amount of `\parindent`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
%\usepackage{times} % times package is obsolete
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array,calc}
\newcolumntype{q}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\begin{document}
\noindent% <-- important
\begin{tabular}{@{}
                p{0.5\textwidth-\tabcolsep} 
                q{0.5\textwidth-\tabcolsep}
                @{}}
\toprule
                      & rtcol0  \\
 leftcol1             & rtcol1  \\
 leftcol2             & rtcol2  \\
 leftcol3             & rtcol3  \\
 leftcol4             & rtcol4  \\
\midrule
 Ref: xxxxxxx                 & Date: yyyyyyy \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*, prompted by a follow-up comment by the OP that the cell contents in neither column would ever overflow, i.e., exceed `0.5\textwidth-\tabcolsep` in width. Given this additional piece of information, setting up the table structure can be simplified considerably, for now one can simply employ a `tabular*` environment (instead of a `tabular` environment) and set its target width to textwidth; all that remains to be done is to select `l` and `r` as the column types.

The LaTeX code would be as follows (no screenshot posted since the visual outcome is the same as above):

```
\noindent% <-- important
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{%
    @{\extracolsep{\fill}} l r @{}}
\toprule
                      & rtcol0  \\
 leftcol1             & rtcol1  \\
 leftcol2             & rtcol2  \\
 leftcol3             & rtcol3  \\
 leftcol4             & rtcol4  \\
\midrule
 Ref: xxxxxxx                 & Date: yyyyyyy \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
```

Comment: Thank you Mico. Excellent reply, both quick and comprehensive

Comment: @chazr - Please also see the addendum I posted: If it's known that no individual cell contents will require automatic line wrapping, the table's design can be simplified considerably.

Comment: Thanks Mico, that addendum is fantastic. I love the way you provide working examples with your solutions.

Answer (score 2):

With table `tblr` of `tabularray` package your table code is short and simple:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\noindent%
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {@{} X[l]X[r] @{}}}
    \toprule
                & rtcol0        \\
 leftcol1       & rtcol1        \\
 leftcol2       & rtcol2        \\
 leftcol3       & rtcol3        \\
 leftcol4       & rtcol4        \\
    \midrule
 Ref: xxxxxxx   & Date: yyyyyyy \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The package `nicematrix` provides an environment `{NiceTabular}` similar to the classical environment `{tabular}` but with new functionalities.

In particular, the columns `p`, `m`, `b` and `X` have an optional argument (between square brackets) for the horizontal alignment.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{NiceTabular}{@{} X[l]X[r] @{}}
\toprule
                & rtcol0        \\
 leftcol1       & rtcol1        \\
 leftcol2       & rtcol2        \\
 leftcol3       & rtcol3        \\
 leftcol4       & rtcol4        \\
\midrule
 Ref: xxxxxxx   & Date: yyyyyyy \\
\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

By default, when a key `X` is used, the width of a `{NiceTabular}` is equal to the parameter `\linewidth`. However, it's possible to change the required width of the tabular with the key `width`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{NiceTabular}[width=8cm]{@{}X[l]X[r]@{}}
\toprule
                & rtcol0        \\
 leftcol1       & rtcol1        \\
 leftcol2       & rtcol2        \\
 leftcol3       & rtcol3        \\
 leftcol4       & rtcol4        \\
\midrule
 Ref: xxxxxxx   & Date: yyyyyyy \\
\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the second code]

Comment: Thanks. Can I set the table width?

Comment: Yes, with the key `width`. I have modified my answer to show an example.

Comment: Thank you. That's a good simple solution.